# How to use client.on in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently using discord.js to develop a discord bot. I wanted to create a function to send a message based on user input.

The code I have is as follows:

```
function myFunction(keyWord) {
   client.on("messageCreate", myMessage => {
   if (myMessage.content.bot) {
      return
   }
   myMessage.channel.send(keyWord)
   })
}
```

When I run this function in my code, the code seems to stop at the `client.on` section. It does not throw an error, it simply does not send the message or run any code beyond the `client.on`.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: that's how asynchronous code works. This just sets up a callback to happen when the client receives the "messageCreate" message/action later. (I'm not personally familiar with discord.js so I may not use the standard terminology for that.)

Comment: also, if you call `myFunction` several times.. when one message is created, the bot would send `keyWord` in the channel as many times as your function was called and not just once

Comment: You also have `})` backwards in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myMessage.content` returns a string; you are reading it as an object.

If you want to check if the author is a bot, you would read `message.author.bot`.

Try the following:

```js
function myFunction(keyWord) {
  client.on('messageCreate', (myMessage) => {
    if (myMessage.author.bot)
      return;

    myMessage.channel.send(keyWord);
  });
}
```